# Import error when I try use "requests" module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem, when try to use requests lib

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.python.org/')
print(r)
```

After that, I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Documents/alex/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .retry import Retry
  File "C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 15, in <module>
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

I do not understand why is it at all. Please, help me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and to help fix the issue) - how is the file you are running the code in is called?

Comment: My file  - test.py

Comment: any other files in the same directory named `logging.py`?

Comment: Yes, your have a logging.py somehwere in your path that is not the builtin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is one of the following

1. Your installation of Python is terribly broken
2. When `C:\Program Files\python3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py` tries to import `logging` it imports wrong file. This may happen because

   - There is file called `logging.py` in the directory you are running your `test.py` from. In this case, you will need to rename it so that `logging` from Python library is imported, not yours.
   - There is file called `logging.py` in one of directories from Python Path and it gets found before the `logging.py` the module actually needs

To check what `logging` gets imported, write the following simple program

```
import logging
import os.path

print os.path.abspath(logging.__file__)
```

Whatever is printed is path to your `logging` file. If it is not along the line of `...\Python\\Python36\\lib\\logging\\__init__.py`, the wrong file is imported and you got to replace/rename it

Comment: Thanks.  Yes...logging.py file in the directory I run test.py... I rename it and all right.